# how to "npm start" with pm2 cluster mode

Tags: node.js, pm2

**this commend start pm2 with cluster mode.**

```
$ pm2 start [app] -i 0
```

**this commend npm start with pm2 process.**

```
$ pm2 start npm -- start
```

So I want npm start of cluster mode.

```
$ pm2 start npm -- start -i 0
```

But "**npm start**" don't start cluster mode.

How to "npm start" with cluster mode on pm2 ?

Answer (score 1):

1. the command line you have above does not seem to be correct. You wrote:

`$ pm2 start npm -- start -i 0`

it should be

`$ pm2 start  app.js -i 0`

[from the docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

2. I would strongly suggest using a pm2.json configuration file so you can place all your needed parameters inside and start PM2 with the Json file.
3. To check if PM2 is actually in cluster mode:
   `PM2 list all` or `PM2 describe [name of app]`
   This will show you detailed information on the running apps.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know start cluster mode to app.js. But I don't know npm start to pm2 cluster mode.

Answer (score 1):

To start command **npm start** in cluster mode in pm2, use this command **pm2 start -i 0 npm -- start**

Answer (score 0):

If you need **npm start** in pm2,

you can create a start.sh at root of your project

```
#!/bin/bash
npm start
```

And use pm2 like that :

```
pm2 start start.sh -i 0 --name appname
```

This worked for me.